# Is static electricity an "electrical discharge"?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge, air, gas

I understand that any electrical discharge such as corona discharge is the scattering of electrical charge through a medium; most likely a gas ("discharging charges").

As the air is a gas, would it be correct to say that "static electricity" is an "electrical discharge"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two states of discharge.

> *[Static electricity]* is an imbalance of electric charges within or on the surface of a material. The charge remains until it is able to move away by means of an electric current or electrical discharge. Static electricity is named in contrast with *current electricity*, which flows through wires or other conductors and transmits energy.

It  describes one of the two stages  before discharge happens, the [static discharge.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_electricity#Static_discharge)